# A linear operator $T:V \longrightarrow V$ is a monomorphism if and only if its matrix representation $[T]_{B_{V}}$ has a trivial nullspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I proved this for all ordered basis $B_{V}$ of $V$. But I would like to consult here if this is true.

Here's how I did it: Note that $[T(\alpha)]_{B_{V}}=[T]_{B_{V}}[\alpha]_{B_{V}}$ for all $\alpha\in V$, where $B_{V}$ is an ordered basis of $V$ and $[\alpha]_{B_{V}}$ indicates the coordinate matrix of $\alpha$ with respect to $B_{V}$.

Let $T$ be a monomorphism and $[T(\alpha)]_{B_{V}}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\\vdots\\0 \end{bmatrix}$. This means that $T(\alpha)=0$, which implies that $\alpha=0$ since $T$ is monomorphism. Therefore, $[T]_{B_{V}}$ has a trivial nullspace.

Conversely, if $[T]_{B_{V}}$ has a trivial nullspace and $T(\alpha)=0$, then $\alpha=0$ since $[T(\alpha)]_{B_{V}}=[T]_{B_{V}}[\alpha]_{B_{V}}$.

Comment: If you proved that, then it is true!

Comment: Maybe, could you show us your proof?

Answer (score 0):

You got the trivial direction, though you should probably remark that $0$ is *always* in the nullspace.

I don't see you getting the converse though.   All you did was restated the condition for trivial nullspace.  The question remains,  why does that imply $T $ is monic.

Here's why:  suppose  $T (\alpha) =T (\beta) $.  Then by linearity,  $T (\alpha-\beta)=0$.  Since the nullspace is trivial,  we get $\alpha-\beta=0\implies \alpha=\beta $.

Comment: I implied it from the fact that $T$ is monomorphism if and only if $\ker T=\{0\}$. I should've stated it in the post.

Comment: I see.  I guess I missed the point.